# A stronger word than "snob"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, vocabulary, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I recently stayed at a charming boarding house and had the pleasure of meeting one of the most curious people I have ever come across in my life. He was polite, and yet standoffish. He reminded me of Basil Fawlty in Fawlty Towers in his servility but without the bursts of uncontrolled rage (thankfully!). During my entire stay I willed myself to find a noun, an adjective or any appropriate expression to describe the landlord in question but I was stunned by his bizarre behaviour. His wife, au contraire, was kind, intelligent, witty and a true saint.

So, a brief description of the landlord's character and I hope someone will supply the word or expression that does the chap justice!

Someone who is concerned with social class; who fancies himself belonging to the upper-middle class when it is clear from his speech and mannerisms he did not enjoy those privileges as a child. A person who is fixated with appearances; always lays the table with expensive looking cutlery, cut lead crystal glasses, linen napkins and even lit candelabras but then serves pre-cooked food bought from Tescos (U.S Walmart). A person who addresses you as a "young lady", is obsequious to a fault but then drinks too much at dinner and slurs his words. Whose talk borders on vulgarity but somehow manages to never cross that line. A person who will boast of owning two cars when he cannot drive. A person who will continually ask if you slept well, if you are enjoying the food, if you are fond of this or that, and whether you are comfortable in the first ten minutes but will then proceed to ignore you for the rest of the evening by watching the television.

What do you call someone like that? During my stay I could only think of *snob* but it seemed so inadequate, so measly compared to the sheer magnificence of his.... what?!

---

**EDIT** [original comments 17/7/2013]

The landlord was always polite, even obsequious, never aggressive nor disdainful towards me because I was "the perfect guest". (I was very conscious about my table manners while staying there!). He was anxious to impress me because I was a visitor from Italy and proclaimed to love Italian music, art, food and wine, while knowing next to nothing about them.

My landlord spoke of his travels abroad, his cruises to islands and he waxed endlessly about how fine the women dressed on board, how they dressed differently during the day and evening and how their handbags and shoes matched their dresses. The man was, frankly speaking, quite bizarre! I've never met anyone quite like him.

He was very right-wing, a real conservative and even expressed admiration for Berlusconi because he is a man of immense wealth and power, while personally I abhor the politician. He did express disapproval about the number of young men and women who would fill the bars, pubs and nightclubs at the week-ends and would often advise me from going out late at night, in case I should witness their vulgar, cheap, drunken behaviour. This piece of advice I always ignored and often enjoyed a pint with friends myself, I had a wonderful time! :)

Comment: Maybe pretentious, stuck-up, supercilious, dandy or elitist?

Comment: Social clamberer?

Comment: @Carlo_R. Definitely never a dandy; supercilious is close but my landlord was not haughty, nor arrogant.

Comment: @jwpat7 His family was well-off, and he benefited from a wealthy inheritance, so social clamberer is appropriate.

Comment: Did you know that Basil Fawlty was inspired by a real-life hotel proprietor - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Sinclair_%28hotel_owner%29 ?

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes, I did actually. I am quite a fan of John Cleese and Connie Booth's comedy masterpiece!

Comment: I’d probably just call him Hyacinth.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's a plant?

Comment: *Hyacinth* is the character in the TV programme *Keeping up appearances*, who has strong pretensions of being upper class, and who despises her sister and family who are very stereo-typical working class. See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119339/what-is-the-origin-of-using-the-word-our-preceding-a-first-name-when-speaking) from yesterday.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that would explain my confusion. I have heard of the series but I've never watched it in Italy or on holiday!

Comment: 'clamberer' is not particularly idiomatic English. Just doesn't sound right. 'To clamber', I had always thought was one of those Alice in Wonderland neologisms (because it is in Jabberwocky), but there are uses before then. Anyway, it just sounds weird. Also anyway, the term you're looking for is 'social _climber_'.

Comment: @Mitch: No, no, *clamberer* is much better, because this person is not exactly succeeding. It's a nice word.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget *bourgeois* and *petite-bourgeoisie*. And why "upper-middle class" specifically: should it exclude the upper classes?

Comment: @Cerberus The British have always had a morbid fascination with the class system. I have always thought upper-class verged on aristocracy. I know that is extremely rare that someone from a middle-class background can become a member of that exclusive circle; think of Kate Middleton. I believe her family is upper-middle class. But I could be wrong, if I am, please correct me.

Comment: @Cerb: it may seem 'right' as a neologism, but [nobody has used it in a book](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Social+clamberer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and [rare on the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22social+clamberer). If you said it outloud you'd fail the spy test.

Comment: @Mitch: Sure, but I don't think the point is whether it is commonly used, but whether it is more appropriate! (And a phrase isn't normally a neologism, even if it's new.) Social climber is a broader term with a slightly different meaning. I would hesitate to call someone who fails a social climber...

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Well, it's not easy, but it's possible, if you send your child to the right schools and he or she hangs out with the right people, adjusts his or her manners a bit. But the point isn't whether it is possible to succeed, should this be a conscious enterprise, but rather whether people try! And they do, all the time. Like Hyacinth. She's not aspiring to middle class, but to upper class, as Trevor said above.

Comment: @Cerberus I checked on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_class) and it says the upper-class "is generally contained within the wealthiest 1-2% of the population," I have never watched the TV programme, but it seems to me a pretty unattainable height to aspire to. The upper-class is not only a position in society but also an indicator of great wealth. Appertaining to the upper-middle class is a more *realistic* ambition.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Almost everyone belonging to traditional upper classes will strongly disagree with that definition, which by the way was taken from a book about African-American culture. This is probably caused by a confusion with the definition commonly used in sociology/economics. But normally, in modern society, it's mainly about who you hang out with and your behaviour, including manners and attitudes. Money and birth help, but they're only secondary. In some past societies, like Rome, money was more important than now. In Renaissance France, titles and genealogy were more important than now.

Comment: Well, I do agree with you about how titles and money were once considered more highly than today, but it is a fact that regardless of my education and the job I have, I will never belong to that bracket. And, I really couldn't care less. Now if someone is able to mix in that privileged circle, and at the same time not have to depend on a full time job in order to pay their food and bills, well good luck to them! It is also significant that the TV show "Keeping up with appearances" could only have been conceived in the UK and nowhere else in the world.

Comment: It hardly seems that a word **stronger** than snob is needed. A snob will not ask you if you slept well or enjoyed the food! Unless he means, "how do these fine accommodations compare to that hovel which you call your home?"  Someone who is more interested in watching television than conversing with some strangers is hardly a snob on account of that.

Comment: @Kaz I've given examples of his snobbery, and I never said he was impolite. In my comments there are further examples of his behaviour.

Comment: I think it's important to note that this is sposta be UK speech. We don't have a class system quite like that in the US, though some would disagree. In any event, the fascination with overt social class is not generally a part of American _assholism_, as Geoff Nunberg calls it. We don't really have the words for it, so only UK speakers' answers are likely to be le mot juste.

Comment: Thank you @JohnLawler, I was born in the UK and although I no longer live there I do remember certain things about the culture and the people.

Comment: Someone who is concerned with things, appearances and social position is materialistic or shallow. Snobbery requires that there be chauvinism: behavior which betrays a belief that people are superior or inferior based on these things. In fact the terms "snob" and "snobbery" are used as synonyms for chauvinism in other areas. A "jazz snob" could be someone who lives in a cardboard box under a bridge, guarding his precious collection of vinyl records of the only stuff that can legitimately be called music.

Comment: @Kaz That's an interesting piece of information, and probably invalidates the title of my question. Oh, dear :( Although he definitely thought himself superior to the majority of young people who drank at the pubs, but that's not really snobbery, is it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA In what way did the man think himself superior to the majority of young people drinking in pubs?

Comment: So far I have this person pinned as some kind of eccentric with a fixation on certain material trappings associated with belonging to a higher class and living the good life (perhaps due to some inferiority complex). That doesn't fit into two words easily, though.

Comment: @Kaz well he was convinced he was better than them, that's for sure. He didn't give say this adjective himself, but he implied the young were "yobs", he spoke of them sneeringly, said they were out of control, and emphasized their violent behaviour. He warned me not to go out at night, said I would witness fights in the streets. I saw nothing of the kind. I did see men who were drunk, and women wobbling on their high heels as they were coming out from hen parties but I'd say they were an extremely cheerful, and high *spirited* bunch. Maybe I was just lucky on those two weekends!

Comment: @Mari: Most people in the upper classes now have to work for a living like everyone else. England has relatively many very rich aristocrats left, because the oldest son used to inherit everything, as opposed to elsewhere; but even there the number has been decreasing for over a century now. And KUA could very well have been conceived in other countries: at least in most of Europe, the upper classes can be characterised in the same way. Lastly, it is true that it's not easy to go from middle to upper, but neither is it easy to go from lower to middle. And, yes, it matters little anyway!

Comment: @Cerberus I think you are mixing up upper-middle class with upper-class. Both classes enjoy privileges but the main difference between them is that the former will have to earn a living in order to maintain that certain living standard. The upper-class own properties, land and whether you like it or not are *born* in that social class. The necessity of a regular wage is not based on paying the rent or mortgage of a house. I found this quote which although humorous has more than a grain of truth.

Comment: RICH HALL, a US stand-up comic, explained: when you go to work in the morning, if your name is on the front of the building, you're upper class; if your name is on your desk, you're middle class; and if your name is on your shirt, you're working class.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I'm afraid I can't agree. Impoverished nobility is not middle or lower class. And, while the t-shirt is funny and perhaps true, having your name on a building does not make you upper class at all; on the contrary, one might say, because it conflicts with certain upper-class norms. Again, I think you're talking about the sociological definition, which is all about economics. Prof. Ross (the famous linguist) ca. 1954: “it is solely by their language that the upper classes nowadays are distinguished since they are neither cleaner, richer, nor better-educated than anybody else".

Comment: @Cerberus I understand the phrase; *if your name is on your shirt*, as being the name you wear on a badge, for example shop assistants, not on a t-shirt.

Comment: @Cerberus I think the discussion is an interesting and worthy one but due to limited characters, it is difficult to deal with in depth. Perhaps a question to the community asking for clarification might be worthwhile asking, as there is evidence that suggests we might be both right!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Haha, I agree, we needn't continue our discussion here; besides, it isn't even directly relevant to your question. Yes, we are both right: we just use different definitions, where mine is the traditional one, and yours probably closer to the one often used in the social sciences. Nothing wrong with either...

Comment: @Skippy I read your suggestion and I snorted to myself. Indeed, prat, is an eloquently succinct word. It does its job. But it's not something I would normally say in company. :)) Yes, a normal every-day word that I can use with my English speaking Italian native speakers friends. Do you get my drift?!

Comment: I should have said: "English speaking Italian friends". I've been on this site too long!

Comment: "Stronger" in what way?  More insulting?  More definitive?  More politically correct?  More well-known?

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis  One which describes his personality **more accurately**. I said I could only think of "snob" at the time (but thanks to the many suggestions posted that is no longer true) and felt it was too weak / inadequate an expression to do the man justice.

Comment: Seems like the word you are looking for then is either 'patronizing' or 'condescending'.  There, I deserve the 250 bounty!

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis he was neither to me, or to the other guests. I've given a fair description of the man.

Comment: I think it is more to do with the fact that my description was unusually detailed for this type of question. If I had left my question as: "A better/more negative/stronger word than snob" and not added any description then the answers would have more or less converged. Complex and unpredictable characters are NOT easy to define in one word, and the man was paradoxical.

Comment: Interestingly, after all the creative, energetic, thoughtful, colorful, well-meaning, helpful, fascinating, and otherwise marvelous comments and answers offered here, there is only one word in this entire discussion which qualifies as a noun which in a single word hits the mark exactly. I realize where it fails, though; it's too effete, isn't it? ;)

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg Which word is that, precisely? A prat? But I did very appreciate your suggestion, poseur, which caused me sleepless nights! :) I will use many of the expressions offered to me in the future, it has been a true feast.

Comment: In the US there's a distinction (among the Irish-American population) between "shanty Irish" and [lace-curtain Irish](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Lace-Curtain%20Irish); lace-curtain Irish consider themselves superior to their neighbors, despite identical backgrounds and current circumstances. (My grandpa used to say that you could tell a lace-curtain Irish house, 'cause there'd be fruit on the table even if nobody was sick.) This won't directly help you - you're asking about a Briton, for one thing - but I thought you might like to know that some things are universal.

Comment: [A bit more on the topic](http://books.google.com/books?id=XV7PFkY9_3oC&pg=PT17&dq=lace-curtain+Irish&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UXbzUdrxOqakiQLThYGADA&ved=0CFkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=lace-curtain%20Irish&f=false), if you're interested.

Comment: No, Mari-Lou. I actually consider prat to be fairly off the mark. Poseur on the other hand is exactly right. Check the definitions. But what I neglected to do was to put it into its Anglicized version, "poser," which lends it the sarcastic force you're looking for (especially when spoken with revulsion). Your choice, of course. (I think I'll go ahead and add "poser" to the answer, just for the sake of completeness.)

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg Yes, as I said, poseur, did cause me sleepless nights, maybe the Brit version would have swayed me then and there. Who knows. But my choice was dictated by the final edit skippy wrote, which was written from the heart I hope she doesn't "correct" or edit it in any way.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg  Perhaps you are unaware of this, but in the UK "prat" is a very common way to insult someone. I can't define it, it's just one of those words that you know instantly when to use it and I know a lot of Brits would have described the landlord as being one. Definitely it belongs to the so-called lower classes, which I thought fitting, I hope my analysis helps to explain why I didn't choose one or the other of the many superb answers. I also appreciated the "All hat no cattle" answer, but it was the first time I had ever heard of it, and I felt it was too "American".

Comment: Oh, quite. I know prat is an insult, and a delightful one. But as a _single_ unmodified word, it means someone who is incompetent, ineffectual, stupid, or foolish (or all of the above), and as such, doesn't even come close to what you want. Even modified, I think it's still just a tad off. But, that's all well and good. No worries. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*[Tutto fumo niente arrosto](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/tutto%20fumo%20niente%20arrosto)* would easily translate in the United States to **[All hat and no cattle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_hat_and_no_cattle)**, which makes reference to a wannabe cowboy (or rancher) who dresses the part but lacks any real personal experience. It means full of big talk but lacking action, power, or substance; pretentious.

[This link](http://yankeeexposure.blogspot.com/2010/05/all-hat-and-no-cattle.html) has a way of describing the expression as being rather derogatory, but has that U.S. Southern sound of politeness (in the same way that "[bless your heart](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bless%20your%20heart)" is used) where one might get away with saying it to a person's face without them realizing how badly they have been stung. You can read the coarse language interpretation yourself at the link, but the oafish target might simply respond "Uh, thanks, so you like my hat?"

Country singer Trace Adkins has a song based on the expression. The lyrics might metaphorically describe your host fairly well:

```
See that boy standing there by the dance floor 
He's lookin' like the Marlboro Man 
Starched shirt, starched jeans, big trophy buckle 
And an empty Copenhagen can 
He's talkin' cowboy this and cowboy that 
Well I'll bet one thing's for sure 
The only stampede that he's ever seen 
Is the clearance at the western store

All hat and no cattle, that boy just ain't real 
All boots and no saddle, don't know how to make a cowgirl feel 
Think I'm gonna tell him to pack up his act 
And go back where he came from 
'Cause all hat and no cattle ain't gonna get it done

He's just a smooth-talkin', long-tall slow-walkin' 
Drugstore-made-up dude 
So honey don't you fall for that fake Texas drawl 
He ain't right for you 
What you need's a man that ain't just a hat stand 
When you get him home 
Well, I don't look like much, but I can sure saddle up 
And ride with you all night long

All hat and no cattle, that boy just ain't real 
All boots and no saddle, don't know how to make a cowgirl feel 
Think I'm gonna tell him to pack up his act 
And go back where he came from 
'Cause all hat and no cattle ain't gonna get it done

All hat and no cattle ain't gonna get it done
```

(You can hear the song at [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFM7teLinOA).)

From a description of [cowboy culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy#Symbolism) in wikipeidia:

> Actual cowboys have derisive expressions for individuals who adopt
>   cowboy mannerisms as a fashion pose without any actual understanding
>   of the culture. For example, a "drugstore cowboy" means someone who
>   wears the clothing but does not actually sit upon anything but the
>   stool of the drugstore soda fountain—or, in modern times, a bar stool.
>   Similarly, **the phrase "all hat and no cattle" is used to describe
>   someone (usually male) who boasts about himself, far in excess of any
>   actual accomplishments.** The word "dude" (or the now-archaic term
>   "greenhorn") indicates an individual unfamiliar with cowboy culture,
>   especially one who is trying to pretend otherwise.

You should know that modern Texans (and Western Americans in general to a lesser degree), take the cowboy culture seriously. - I would imagine that the wealthiest oil barons, ranchers, sport team owners, and techno-wizards of the region would treat the cowboy culture just as the British Royals treat their foxhunting and equestrian sports. The phrase "all hat and no cattle" would be an often used phrase among these elite. (If you have ever acquainted yourself with the television series "Dallas", you may understand this better.)

By the way, let me point out the word **wannabe** that I used in the description above. (Wannabe cowboy, meaning someone who wants to be a cowboy or rancher).  "[Wannabe](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wannabe)" is a derogatory noun, one who aspires, often vainly, to emulate another's success or attain eminence in some area.

---

**[Stuffed shirt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stuffed+shirt)** (n) a pompous, self-satisfied, and inflexible person.

**[Pretentious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pretentious?s=t&ld=1146)** (adj) characterized by assumption of dignity or importance, especially when exaggerated or undeserved; making an exaggerated outward show; ostentatious.

**[Pompous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pompous?s=t)** (adj) characterized by an ostentatious display of dignity or importance

**[Prideful](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prideful)** (adj) having a high or inordinate opinion of one's own dignity, importance, merit, or superiority, whether as cherished in the mind or as displayed in bearing, conduct, etc.

**[Supercilious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/supercilious)** (adj) displaying arrogant pride, scorn, or indifference; feeling or showing haughty disdain.

**[Vainglorious](http://thesaurus.com/browse/vainglorious)** - characterized by or exhibiting excessive vanity; boastful.

Slurring his speech while drinking at dinner makes me think of 
**[bumptious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bumptious)** - (adj) presumptuously, obtusely, and often noisily self-assertive; full of ones self.

Of course, adding "jerk" or, better yet, "ass" to any of these adjectives makes them more disdainful, as with *pretentious jerk* or *pompous ass*.

Comment: Up vote, though I'd suggest "proud" instead of "prideful". Don't forget "haughty". It is gender-neutral.

Comment: Yes, at some point this list and a moderately good thesaurus points to so many related words. I had to stop. I do think prideful is more commonly understood in a negative sense, even though it is not necessarily so. :)

Comment: After seeing this fine list I now realize why OPs rarely up-vote these type of answers. Each word describes, to a certain extent, a facet of his character but grouped together they give a distorted view of the person. The landlord was always polite, even obsequious, never aggressive or disdainful towards me, because I was "the perfect guest".(I was very conscious about my table manners while staying there!). He was anxious to impress me because I was a visitor from Italy and proclaimed to love Italian music, art, food and wine, while knowing next to nothing about them.

Comment: He was very right-wing, a real conservative and even expressed admiration for Berlusconi because he is a man of immense wealth and power, while personally, I abhor the politician. He did express disapproval about the number of young men and women who would fill the bars, pubs and night clubs at the week-ends and would often advise me from going out late at night, in case I should witness their vulgar, cheap drunken behaviour. This piece of advice I always ignored and often enjoyed a pint with friends myself, I had a wonderful time! :)

Comment: Have you considered that he may have only been *socially awkward*? My first thought was to be charitable in describing the gentleman rather than searching for the superlative negative term. Hanlon's razor might apply, after all (http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor). And his admiration of Berlusconi may have something to do with the man knowing how to party, something socially akward people have trouble with! :)

Comment: No, I can recognize awkwardness and when someone is consciously covering his or her lack of social graces because they feel embarrassed. He was nothing of the sort. The man enjoyed more than a drink or two but expressed disdain towards the local men or women who filled the bars at night. That to me smacks of hypocrisy.

Comment: He had taste (or his wife did) concerning the décor of his house, and I felt like entering a Victorian home whenever we went to the "drawing room" (his expression not mine). There were some great pieces of furniture, crockery (?), prints of famous paintings, ornaments, silverware. It really felt like travelling back in time. The bathroom and kitchen were, however, thoroughly modern.

Comment: My landlord spoke of his travels abroad, his cruises to islands and he waxed endlessly about how fine the women dressed on board, how they dressed differently during the day and evening and how their handbags and shoes matched their dresses. The man was, frankly speaking, quite bizarre! I've never met anyone quite like him.

Comment: There were three answers I was torn between at the time of the bounty, yours was one of them.

Answer (score 24):

**[Prig](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prig)**

> a person who displays or demands of others pointlessly precise conformity, fussiness about trivialities, or exaggerated propriety, especially in a self-righteous or irritating manner.
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prig): a person who shows an inordinately zealous approach to matters of form and propriety – especially where the prig has the ability to show superior knowledge to those who do not know the protocol. They see little need to consider the feelings or intentions of others, relying instead on established order and rigid rules to resolve all questions.
>
> The prig approaches social interactions with a strong sense of self-righteousness.

A perhaps even better description would be

**A pretentious prig**

since it gives the impression that the prigness does not stem from actual superiority

Alternative:

**Hypocritical plebeian prig**

Comment: That's a good one. The landlord was fussy over details that were trivial but according to the dictionary definition you posted; a prig could be cultured, belonging to a high social class and be knowledgeable about "protocol". My landlord wanted to give this impression but it was all pretence. Very superficial. In Italian there is the saying: [tutto fumo poco/niente arrosto](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/tutto%20fumo%20niente%20arrosto) which comes close.

Comment: Hypocritical plebeian prig ;)

Comment: I would have said that *prig* has implications of "standoff-ish", which may not be appropriate from Mari-Lou's description.

Comment: I read this in the wikipedia link you provided: "Another famous portrait of a prig is that of Malvolio in Shakespeare's Twelfth Night... **He is a prig with an instinct for grandeur**" which is pretty apt, me thinks.

Comment: And pretentious is something like Mrs Bucket from keeping up appearances

Comment: @Mari-LouA In case you hadn't realised: *Mrs Bucket* (referred to in mplugjan's comment) is the afore-mentioned *Hyacinth* from *Keeping up appearances*, and she insists on pronouncing her surname as *Bouquet*.

Comment: Thanks, @TrevorD I hadn't realized. Her posh way of pronouncing "Bucket" tickles me no end; you've convinced me that the programme is worth watching. Which series would you recommend?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm afraid I haven't got enough knowledge to recommend a particular series, altho' I've probably seen them all over the years. The series ended in 1995, but repeats are still broadcast regularly, and we've certainly watched at least part of an episode in the past 2 weeks. Each episode is only a half-hour. There's a useful summary of the programme in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_up_appearances).

Comment: @TrevorD the show ended 1995?! Good ole BBC; do they still do repeats of "Some mother's do 'av 'em"? :) No need to answer, this is becoming dangerously "off topic"

Comment: Amusingly, Mrs. Bucket came up in conversation tonight. I'd never heard of her before.

Comment: Ah, I believe that's "Buckette", ahem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Keeping_Up_Appearances_characters#Hyacinth_Bucket

Answer (score 11):

One who makes a great pretense and display of belonging to a much higher class than that to which he or she actually belongs, and of possessing much more elegance and refinement than he or she actually possesses, and who unjustifiably looks down upon those who do not attain to his or her *pretended* level, is a ***poseur.***

Adding just a bit here: The Anglicized version, ***poser***, lends the additional forcefulness sought in the original question, especially when it's spoken with the requisite level of dismissive revulsion. Although many of the suggestions made in answer here are really excellent, I think this is the only single word which truly fills the bill with reasonable precision.

Comment: If I could upvote twice I would.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:**

I would describe him as being ***a smug, mealy-mouthed, ostentatious, gaudy, self-serving, self-satisfied ninny or boob.***

Now, if you'd rather not use the word prat in company, I suggest refining the above to :

I had such an ***ostentatious and smug*** landlord.  ;-) hehehe

[Smug](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smug)

> 1. excessively self-satisfied or complacent

[Mealy-mouthed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mealy-mouthed)

> avoiding the use of direct and plain language, as from timidity,
>   excessive delicacy, or hypocrisy; inclined to mince words; insincere,
>   devious, or compromising.

[Ostentatious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ostentatious)

> characterized by or given to pretentious or conspicuous show in an
>   attempt to impress others: an ostentatious dresser.

[Gaudy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ostentatious)

> 1. brilliantly or excessively showy: gaudy plumage.
> 2. cheaply showy in a tasteless way; flashy.
> 3. ostentatiously ornamented; garish.

[Self-satisfied](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-satisfied)

> 1. self-satisfied - marked by excessive complacency or self-satisfaction; "a smug glow of self-congratulation"
> 2. smug, complacent, proud of yourself, well-pleased, puffed up,
>      self-congratulatory, flushed with success, pleased with yourself, like
>      a cat that has swallowed the canary, too big for your boots or
>      breeches You're so bloody self-satisfied.

[Self-serving](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self-serving)

> 1. preoccupied with one's own interests, often disregarding the truth or
>      the interests, well-being, etc., of others.
> 2. serving to further one's own selfish interests.

[Ninny](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ninny)

> Fool, simpleton

[Boob](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boob)

> British . a blunder; mistake.

*I hope my infused humor is appreciated*

---

**A  prat.**
More contemptible
**A pretentious prat**

**A *person characterized by assumption of dignity or importance, especially when exaggerated or undeserved*; who is *an incompetent,  ineffectual, arse.***

I won't list all the synonyms, but suffice to say, it is a word I use frequently, particularly prefaced with [pretentious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pretentious); and has the dual meaning of arse.

I live in a ['well-to-do'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/well-to-do) area and the number of '[would-bes](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/would-be)-if-they-could-bes' clambering to get their children into the local schools and putting on [airs and graces](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/airs-and-graces) to gain what they believe to be acceptance. Dealing also with the ['nouveau riche'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nouveau+riche) with an underlying insecurity and self doubt. Basically these people confuse the 'money with the man' so to speak.  *Did you like my flood of cliches??* So imagine Basil Fawlty times 1000.. **:-/**

**Prat**

[— n
slang](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prat)  an incompetent or ineffectual person: often used as a term of abuse

[noun

informal](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prat)  
1British an incompetent or stupid person; an idiot.
2a person’s buttocks.

[British](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prat)
: a stupid or foolish person

*NB I could not find a decent link for "confuse the money with the man" any finders??*

---

**Edit 2**

I am offering this insight into my own experience so, when I comment, people will understand, I am not being mean spirited, but commenting out of my experience with these matters.

I am Australian and have always lived in the well-to-do areas (that is all I will elaborate). I have rubbed shoulders with all sorts in all directions and can hold my own in any social class.

I married an English man, who's mother (yes, my mother in law) was extremely pretentious and in the most [egregious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/egregious) manner.

Where I live, some people pride themselves on being snobs. It is a, relatively neutral term. It sounds [crass](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crass) when people take pride in it. I for one, know, that I am a snob, but spend most of my life trying to hide this and not be like this. (the first is easier than the latter). I mean even making that statement is just, wrong,...

I have downvoted the answers with terms that the likes of, my mother-in-law and your landlord, in question are likely to use.

Prig, Priggish, plebian or pleb, supercilious, vainglorious, poseur and parvenu (and, yes, ostentatious).

These are the sort of words the pretentious use (trust me, I spent my life avoiding them).

When describing someone, as you require, to do so effectively, entails, not using a description that reflects the same status upon the speaker!! Makes sense??
I personally don't use snot, or snoot, but have English friends who would look at this man, wrinkle their noses and use these words, aptly. I, personally, like prat and it is socially acceptable. To me it sums up any man who puffs himself up, and man, I'm surrounded by them.

This is within the context of a culture which shuns self-promotion. An example of the Australian attitudes of the [ostentatious](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h3TD19zeKA) :-)

Comment: I liked your final edit.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I'm really having trouble understanding what word or words were accepted here as answering your question. Is it somewhere in the final edit? Several of the highlighted words in the original seem to touch on parts of the character attributes you described, while others (ptat, boob, ninny, gaudy) wouldn't begin to describe the man. Prig and poseur are closer to the mark.

Comment: @Skippy, why does your dislike of "high-brow" words warrant down votes? I didn't see any especially high-brow, and even if some of them were, wouldn't it make sense to point this out individually, so we can all recognze which ones they are?

Comment: Ah @Jim leave it alone. I liked the sentiment; Skippy connected to the story and that final edit clinched it for me. I was differing until then, time was running out and I made my choice. My bounty. My decision. Visitors can make their own minds up as to which answer fits best. And Jim, one more thing, please direct any questions to me under my post and not someone else's.

Comment: @Mari-Lou No problem, just giving some feedback. Not looking to offend anyone.

Comment: To cheer you all up look at these clips. They are both hilarious 1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz2-ukrd2VQ 2)http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJ0nFQgRApY

Comment: Be careful using "prat".  It is offensive because it means buttocks.

Comment: @Theresa that's the first time I've heard that. Hm in Australia it doesn't, but that doesn't help readers where it does I guess.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be [affected](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affected). This seems a good fit to me because this man tends to misrepresent himself by *affecting* attitudes not his own (e.g. acting as if he belongs to a different social set).

Answer (score 4):

The word that comes to my mind is *unctuous*, which Webster's *Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), defines as "full of unction; *esp* revealing or marked by a smug, ingratiating, and false earnestness or spirituality." The meaning of *unction* that this definition refers to, I believe, is "exaggerated, assumed, or superficial earnestness of language or manner." Another meaning of *unction* is "something used for anointing: ointment, unguent," so you get an element of oiliness with the word, as well.

Comment: Unctuous is a good word, but is too negative for the man and reminds me of slimy and sliminess. I could never describe him as that. Although I do agree with the "false earnestness of language or manner" bit.

Comment: I quite like the word and thought it didn't deserve the negative score.  Thanks Sven!

Answer (score 3):

As you said...

> ...so measly compared to the sheer magnificence of his [**grandiose**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grandiose) [**vainglorious**](http://beta.thesaurus.com/browse/vainglorious) [**meretriciousness**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meretriciousness?s=t).

Or

...he is an [**egocentric**](http://m.dictionary.com/d/?q=egocentric) [**aggrandizer**](http://m.dictionary.com/definition/aggrandizer/?linkId=ibc5yn)

That about covers it...

Answer (score 3):

There are lot many like as follow..

> parvenu,
>   vulgarian,
>   snoot,
>   haughty,
>   perky.

Choose whatever you like..

Regards..

Answer (score 3):

I propose [hoity-toity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoity-toity), especially for its second meaning according to Merriam-Webster:

> having or showing the insulting attitude of people who think that they are better, smarter, or more important than other people

There is also another lovely (I think at least) word I just came across (same source) : [highfalutin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/highfalutin) meaning:

> pretentious, fancy
>
> and pompous (though this last one refers mainly to language use).

Answer (score 2):

**Snot and Prig**

The meaning of these words completely describe a person like your case in my culture.
I'm agree with mplungjan.

Answer (score 2):

He seems to have portrayed a number of characteristics, including obsequiousness, and I don't know whether you may have considered him to be maladroit on account of his failed attempts at impressing.

A person may have a humble background, but still have an appreciation of fine things, that they seek to surround themselves with, that goes beyond a superficial concern with the status such things are ordinarily intended to afford, and to an extent, display a slightly eccentric or incongruous set of characteristics, which they nevertheless make their own, and which has a certain integrity to it, and which one might say is well performed. Your host may have been a rather harmless soul, caught in conflicting notions of self-worth predicated on the perceived value of certain ‘airs and graces’ which made for a rather inept performance by comparison.

I've just found the other word I was searching for in my mind which is: *grotesque*

Comment: +1 for his behaviour is based "on the perceived value of certain 'airs and graces'"

Answer (score 2):

I'm no psychologist/psychiatrist, but sounds to me this poor soul is suffering from a bizarre mix of narcissistic and histrionic personality disorders and perhaps even a disorder all his own!

I would have to proffer the term 'mentally disordered' to satisfy your requirements.

- Narcissistic personality disorder

Persons with this disorder present severely overly-inflated feelings of self-worth, grandiosity, and superiority over others. Persons with narcissistic personality disorder often exploit others who fail to admire them, and are overly sensitive to criticism, judgment, and defeat.

- Histrionic personality disorder

Persons with this disorder are overly conscious of their appearance, are constantly seeking attention, and often behave dramatically in situations that do not warrant this type of reaction. The emotional expressions of persons with histrionic personality disorder are often judged as superficial and exaggerated.

From: http://medicalcenter.osu.edu/patientcare/healthcare_services/mental_health/mental_health_about/personality/Pages/index.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most fun threads I have seen on Stack Exchange!

To my eye, the most obnoxious characteristic of this charming man is that he is all style and no substance. I lived in Texas for many years, so I love the expression "All hat and no cattle," (user: Canis Lupus) but it seems misplaced for this seemingly *nouveau riche* man (user: user52080), or perhaps more accurately, *nouveau bourgeois*. If you want a colorful analogy, I believe you could start with "all style and no substance" and substitute words that are personal to his character. "Two cars and no license." "All dress and no tango." It seems the possibilities are endless with this man.

As a teenager in the US, one of the most damning insults of the skater subculture was "poser" (from *poseur*, see user: John M. Landsberg). Of the suggestions so far, I firmly believe the American spelling, poser, is the best word to describe your long-toothed, faux-deaf host. "Poser," by itself, is highly dependent on context, however, so it does not capture what kind of poser he is. "Snob" at least tells the listener that the man is overly concerned with social class.

user52080 wrote something that I believe is profoundly insightful: the description must be something that could not be answered with, "Now the pot is calling the kettle 'black.'" This insight, I believe, helps to narrow the field of accurate descriptions.

In total, I doubt there is a single word or already existent phrase to describe him. The quantity and quality of the suggested words in this thread, but the absence of a perfect description, is strong evidence that the man is *sui generis*. I think you should invent your own phrase for him. Above, I suggested some variation of "all cattle and no hat," which could be fun to invent a new phrase each time you tell the story.

**My suggestion, however, is *bourgeois poseur*** because I feel that it captures most of the qualities you described, and it is even more damning than *nouveau riche* because he is not even aspiring to be a member of the highest class of society.

Answer (score 1):

The word you may be looking for is ***parvenu*** .

See [wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parvenu%E2%80%8E) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parvenu)

for an explanation. However, this word is applicable only if the person has actually moved to a higher social class from a lower one; not if they just pretend to be of a higher social class.

A less stuffy word you can use is ***wannabe***

Comment: I like the implications of this word and it could explain the person's behaviour. Unfortunately, although he did confess to coming into a bit of money I do not know if he actually moved to a higher class. His family might have already been wealthy to begin with.

Comment: Not only is "wannabe" less stuffy, it is much more common in the wild, and frankly much more English. "parvenu" is a straight-up French word, as is the more common term [nouveau riche](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nouveau+riche). (Does it say more about English speakers or French speakers that we borrow terms of extreme social condescension straight from the French with no alteration?)

Comment: @T.E.D. not quite without alteration, in French an *arriviste* could be new to anything, as borrowed into English, only money.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the meaning of the word "prig" but dislike how it sounds too similar to "prick", you could always try the adjective "priggish". Perhaps "priggish snob" or some other adjective+noun combination.

Comment: Yes 'Prig' sounds very lower class, as does 'snob' or 'snot'.  I'd avoid using them myself.

Answer (score 1):

- condescending
- patronizing
- lordly
- lofty
- snooty
- disdainful
- toffee-nosed

Answer (score 1):

Not a word but two phrases for you. "Fur coat and no knickers" (but the origins of that may make it somewhat unacceptable for use) and "mutton dressed up as lamb"

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of your vignette of this man, to describe him as an **obsequious, self-absorbed and hypocritical snob** seems as accurate a summation as any:

- 'Obsequious' covers his apparent solicitude in securing your good opinion of his establishment and hospitality;
- 'Self-absorbed' captures the shallowness of his actual interest in other people, coupled with his fondness for talking about himself and his claimed accomplishments;
- 'Snob' relates to your host's manifest belief in his own social, cultural and moral superiority, as well as his fixation on the trappings of elevated social status; and
- 'Hypocritical' points to the discrepancy between his judgmental pronouncements about others and his own behavioural shortcomings.

(He could as validly be termed a **prig** as a **snob.** I also think the pleasing sonic similarity of 'prig' and 'prick' is rather fortuitous.)

Comment: Oh dear, my question/bounty is attracting some very good "new" answers!

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a word or two to encapsulate the man, but I doubt it's possible to satisfactorily capture all of his contradictions and his intricacy in the span of just two words.

But here's my attempt at distilling all your comments about him into the sort of brief description you might write for a character in a novel:

He was a churlish boor who fancied himself a proper gentleman. He vacillated between haughty standoffishness and the sort of genteel displays he (mistakenly) thought suited a person of high standing.

And here's my attempt at an even shorter phrase:

A boor putting on airs.

(But perhaps that's a little too negative. It sounds like, in spite of his unpleasantness, there was something likable about him, too.)

Answer (score 1):

"Supercilious" qualifies through being a near-homophone to "super silly ass", as pointed out on  [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/supercilious).

Also, if someone strongly resembles a literary character, why not use that character to render him/her? For instance, "a Babbitt" leaves few people in doubt (not that it fits here). One can even modestly attempt some arithmetics on characters, for instance "a lot of Babbitt with some Sackville-Baggins into the bargain".

Answer (score 0):

Characters like him abound in British literature.  You could call him, say, *a Cecil Vyse* after the character in, *A Room With A View* by E. M. Forster.

[Description of Vyse](http://www.gradesaver.com/a-room-with-a-view/study-guide/character-list/):

> Cecil is handsome and refined. He is also arrogant, unimaginative, and overbearing. He is completely unable to see the beauty in human beings, and he looks down his nose at everyone outside his circle of friends and acquaintances in the London aristocracy.

Answer (score 0):

To me this person sounds "unpleasant"! The detail about women on cruises wearing matching handbags and shoes is hilarious. (PS Cecil Vyse is not a member of the aristocracy, he's just upper-middle-class. Real aristocrats have titles and lands, and don't have to be as pretentious as Cecil.)

Answer (score 0):

Appearing somewhat of a parvenu perhaps? Someone nouveau riche?

Comment: Parvenu has been suggested by three different users, so despite it being an accurate description I  cannot upvote your answer.